# jQuery selector not attaching correctly in different scenarios

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

So I am using a piece of jQuery to check for dirty forms and produce a "Are you sure?" when trying to leave the page without saving changes.

This is included in the header...

```
$(function() {
    $('.AreYouSure').areYouSure();
});
```

And I have a debug thing which uses a form and if you enter something in the input and then try to refresh the jQuery **works OK**.

```
    <?php // DEBUG POKING STICK THING ?>
    <?php if ( $UserCompany == '1' ) { ?>
        <div style="position:absolute; top:0; right:0; margin-right:10px; margin-top:5px; background-color:#4771A5; border-radius:3px; padding:5px; box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) inset, 0px 0px 25px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.7);">
            <form class="AreYouSure" action="" method="POST">
                <input type='text' size='20' name='Poke' placeholder='Magic Poking Stick' style="margin-right:5px; vertical-align:middle; text-align:center;">&nbsp;<input type='submit' name='BadBoyPoke' value='' class='submit' title='Search' maxlength="3" style='background-image:url(&quot;img/bms121.png&quot;); vertical-align:middle;' >  
            </form>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

As you can see I have attached this to the class "AreYouSure" (When trying to select all form tags it didn't work)

When I have a more complicated form it doesn't want to work. I am sure it's something to do with the way the form is set out but I struggling to find out what. The following **does not work**...

```
<div class="TabbedViewContainer">
    <div class="TabbedNavContainer">
        <div style="position: relative;  top: 50%;  transform: translateY(-50%);">
            <?php if ( $claim != '' && $ClaimCompleted == TRUE ) { ?>
                <form class="AreYouSure" action="" method="post">
                <?php if ( $claimTab == '3rdPartyDetails' ) { ?>
                    <a style="text-decoration:underline !important;" href="claims.php?claimID=<?php echo $claim; ?>&claimTab=3rdPartyDetails"><?php echo $LANG_Claims_3rd_Party_Details; ?></a>
                <?php }else{ ?> 
                    <a href="claims.php?claimID=<?php echo $claim; ?>&claimTab=3rdPartyDetails"><?php echo $LANG_Claims_3rd_Party_Details; ?></a>
                <?php } ?>                          
                <?php if ( $claimTab == '3rdPartyDetails' ) { ?>
                    <input name="submit3rd" type="submit" value="<?php echo $LANG_Claims_Submit_3rd_Party_Details; ?>" />
                <?php } ?>                                          
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
    </div>                              
    <?php if ( $claimTab == '3rdPartyDetails' && $ClaimCompleted == TRUE ) { ?>
        <?php
            $ClaimQuery = "SELECT * FROM 3rdPartyClaims WHERE ClaimID = '$claim'";
            $ClaimResult = mysqli_query($db, $ClaimQuery); 
            $ClaimRow = mysqli_fetch_array($ClaimResult, MYSQL_ASSOC);
        ?>
        <div style="text-align:left; padding-left:10px; padding-top:10px;">
            <span style="font-size: 12px; font-weight:bold;"><?php echo $LANG_Claims_ID . $claim; ?><?php echo $LANG_Claims_3rd_Party_Information; ?></span>
            <br />
            <hr size='1' style=" margin: 5px 10px 2px 0; ">
                <table style="float:left;">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align:left;"><?php echo $LANG_Claims_Contact_Name; ?>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td><input name="3rdPartyName" type="text" class="textfield" size="20" value="<?php echo $ClaimRow['3rdPartyName']; ?>"><br /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align:left;"><?php echo $LANG_Claims_Contact_Phone; ?>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td><input name="3rdPartyPhone" type="text" class="textfield" size="20" value="<?php echo $ClaimRow['3rdPartyPhone']; ?>"><br /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align:left;"><?php echo $LANG_Claims_Contact_Email; ?>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td><input name="3rdPartyEmail" type="text" class="textfield" size="20" value="<?php echo $ClaimRow['3rdPartyEmail']; ?>"><br /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align:left;"><?php echo $LANG_Claims_Address1; ?>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td><input name="3rdPartyAddress1" type="text" class="textfield" size="20" value="<?php echo $ClaimRow['3rdPartyAddress1']; ?>"><br /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align:left;"><?php echo $LANG_Claims_Address2; ?>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td><input name="3rdPartyAddress2" type="text" class="textfield" size="20" value="<?php echo $ClaimRow['3rdPartyAddress2']; ?>"><br /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align:left;"><?php echo $LANG_Claims_Postcode; ?>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td><input name="3rdPartyPostcode" type="text" class="textfield" size="20" value="<?php echo $ClaimRow['3rdPartyPostcode']; ?>"><br /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table style="float:left; padding-left:10px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align:left;"><?php echo $LANG_Claims_Damage; ?>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td style="text-align:left;">
                            <textarea name="damage" class="textfield" rows="3" style="width:200px;"><?php echo (str_replace("\\r\\n","&#13;",$ClaimRow['Damage'])); ?></textarea>
                        </td>
                    </tr>   
                    <tr>    
                        <td style="text-align:left;"><?php echo $LANG_Claims_Incident; ?>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td style="text-align:left;">
                            <textarea name="incident" class="textfield" rows="3" style="width:200px;"><?php echo (str_replace("\\r\\n","&#13;",$ClaimRow['Incident'])); ?></textarea>
                        </td>
                    </tr>   
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>                                  
</div>
```

Anyone able to help?

Comment: What do you mean `does not work`? Are you getting an error? Nothing happens? Have you checked the debugger console for errors?

Comment: Might not be the solution to your problem but you should fix your markup. Right now you close the divs containing your form before you close the form tag. You also open and close the form tag based on different if statements which seems a bit weird to me.

Comment: does not work as in no errors, nothing happens it is if it doesn't trigger at all.

Comment: @nbon I agree it's a complete mess however it's a bit difficult as I am working with a weird layout which makes it difficult to manage. My initial thought is that I am closing the form's container div within the form. Maybe someone can confirm if this is deffinately the issue.

Comment: This is a screenshot to explain how weird the layout is: http://prntscr.com/aaanke

Comment: Well if all of the tabs should use the same form you should have the form wrap the TabbedViewContainer. Otherwise you need to have one form per tab and close it within that tab.

Comment: To confirm the issue is the markup. I moved around the form tag as a test and it worked ok. I just need to workout how to restructure the markup

Answer (score 0):

To fix my issue I had to make sure that the FORM tags were kept within one DIV and not spread across multiple DIVs.